# Mulitple Foriegn keys in same table in Django?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I would like to create a form in Django that stores data in a model that contains 1) Name of the Bus service 2) Source 3) Destination 4)trip_distance and 5)entry_timestamp.

I would also like to keep The names of the service, source and destinations in separate database tables. So the user can select these from drop down menus while filling the form.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.service_name

class Source(models.Model):
    source_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.source_name

class Destination(models.Model):
    destination_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.destination_name

class EntryForm(models.Model):
    service= models.ForeignKey(Service)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination)
    trip_distance = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class GlobalOption(models.Model):
    config_option = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

Here is what i have come up with.

Now when i try to create an EntryForm through the shell , i get the following error

```
q = Service.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q
<Service: Rajasthan Roadways>
q.entryform_set.create(source = 'Midwest',destination = 'Sahara',trip_distance = 10000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 752, in create
    return super(RelatedManager, self.db_manager(db)).create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 346, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 468, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 635, in __set__
    self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Midwest'": "EntryForm.source" must be a "Source" instance.
```

How can i design this better? I can manually create EntryForm objects via the admin and then it works.

In this django tutorial a similar line works and does not give this error

```
>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)

# Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
>>> q.choice_set.all()
[]

# Create three choices.
>>> q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
```

Why can't i similarly create the EntryForm object? Also i would like a form to save data to this model so what can i name it?

Comment: How can you fix _what_? The `source` field is a `ForeignKey`. As the error states you cannot assign a string such as `'Midwest'`. It has to be a `Source` object. You can _first_ create a `Source` object then use it as the value of `EntryForm.source`. By the way, naming a model `EntryForm` is very confusing because it is _not_ a form.

Comment: Yes, but it is better to name your model something like `Entry` and reserve the name `EntryForm` for the actual Django `Form` class.

Comment: How can i design these models better? What would be the best way to model this problem in which i have one table for entries and couple of other tables for sources and destinations etc?

Comment: Choice fields are simple `CharField`s, _not_ `ForeignKey`s. I suggest you to read the tutorial from the beginning. Your question (what would be the best way...) is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you are asking how to set up the models. You could group the `Source` and `Destination` into one Model, call it `Place`, because they seem all to refer to places.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.service_name

class Place(models.Model):
    source_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.source_name

class Connection(models.Model):
    service= models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='connections')
    source = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='departing_connections')
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='arriving_connections')
    trip_distance = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    entry_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Only in your `Connection` model you separate them into `source` and `destination` fields again. Adding `related_name` makes it easier to read, for example

```
p = Place.objects.get(pk=1)

from_here = p.departing_connections.all()

this_year = from_here.filter(service__entry_timestamp__year=date.today().year
```

Before you can add `Connection`s, you need to add `Service` and `Place` objects, for the connections to relate to.

Comment: That was nice. However, for my use, there will never be departing connections and only arriving connections. So i wanted to create a seperate  table for source and destination so that the user could select from a smaller list of  sources and destinations.